# run thread immediately after runserver in docker django

Tags: django, multithreading, docker, dockerfile

i want to run a thread in my django project after runserver and everything in local deployment is OK:

scraper/apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
import threading

class ScraperConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'scraper'
    def ready(self):
        from .functions import start_scraper
        threading.Thread(target=start_scraper).start()
```

But in docker deployment the server not runs until this thread done complete!
this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITTEBYTEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./core .

RUN pip3 install pip --upgrade
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD yes yes | python3 manage.py makemigrations && \
        python3 manage.py migrate && \
        yes yes | python3 manage.py collectstatic && \        
        python3 manage.py create_superuser && \
        python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${SCRAPER_OUTER_PORT}
```

##### it is so amazing that I can run this thread as a request in an endpoint of a rest api in this server without any problem. But I want to run this auotomaticaly , immediately after runserver

I think problem is from Dockerfile configs. thanks for your responses and solutions before

## I tried this methods:

1. python:3.8-slim-buster image
2. ubuntu:20.04 image
3. run server with gunicorn
4. run server with asgi application
5. run all CMD as an init.sh file and make executable it(chmod +x) before

all of them not solved my problem

Comment: Since you're using `manage.py runserver`, you might be running into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814615/how-to-avoid-appconfig-ready-method-running-twice-in-django .

Comment: It is other problem. in local deployment that function tuns twice. for a solution i run it as a command in command directory of app. my problem is in docker deployment the server not runs until this thread done complete!

Comment: If the function runs twice in development, it will probably run twice in Docker. I'm wondering if the thread you're starting is blocking. Something similar is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430517/kill-sub-threads-when-django-restarts . That said, does your scraper *have* to run as a thread? Or could it run in its own container as its own process?